# Как убрать ограничение максимального количества пользователей без доступа к админке dle

Tags: php, mysql, dle

Есть полный доступ к файлам сайта и бд, CMS DLE, пароль к админке неизвестен.

Чтобы получить админку хочу регнуть нового пользователя и через бд перевести его в ранг администраторов, но включено ограничение на регистрацию новых пользователей.

Как это обойти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/engine/data/config.php

Ищем значение  `max_users`, устанавливаем его в 0

```
'max_users' => '0'
```

также нужно разрешить регистрацию

```
'allow_registration' => '1'
```